# function to add note on single Woo Commerce product page for downloadable variations

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

Trying to create a simple function that will display a text note above the "add to cart" button on any page displaying a downloadable product in Woo Commerce. I can get it to work for simple products but not for variations. Can anyone help me adjust this code to work for variable products? Thanks so much.

Here's what I have:

```
//add text note to product page for all downloadable products
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_add_to_cart_button' , 'append_download_note' );
function append_download_note() {
  global $product;
    if ( $product->is_downloadable() )  {
      echo '<p>Please note: a link to your downloadable product will be 
      available on the purchase confirmation page.</p>';
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For variable product, it's not the product that you need to test but the variations :

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_add_to_cart_button' , function () {

    global $product;


    $downloadable = FALSE;


    if ("simple" === $product->get_type()) {

        $downloadable = $product->is_downloadable();

    } elseif ("variable" === $product->get_type()) {

        $variations = $product->get_available_variations();

        foreach ($variations as $variation) {

            if ($variation["is_downloadable"]) {
                $downloadable = TRUE;
                break;
            }

        }

    }



    if ($downloadable) {
          echo '<p>Please note: a link to your downloadable product will be 
          available on the purchase confirmation page.</p>';
    }


});
```

Comment: Hey mmm--your code is money. Thank you so much, I owe you a beer. Great solution, I've learned some key things here. You have no idea how many hours I was spinning my wheels on this problem.